# Jquery function not called

Tags: php, jquery

I have jquery function that calls a php script some data from my mysql database, the jquery function is called as below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  getTopFiveDeals();
```

When this runs it gets the data fine and builds some HTML and inserts it into the webpage. As shown below:

```
   $('ul.special-list').append("<li><a href='#' class=restaurantItem  restaurant= '" + item.estName + "' adddress='" + item.estAddr + "'><img src= " + item.img_link + 
        " width='60' height='60' alt='" + item.estName + "'><div class='img-det'><strong class='title'> " + item.title + " </strong><p> " + item.desc_short +
        " <br>Expires: " + item.expiry_date + " </p><em class='price'>" + item.price + "</em></div></a><a href='dealDetail.html?id=" + item.id +
        "' class='det-link'>Detail</a>");
```

The problem starts when i have a simple jquery function  below. The function is not called instead the page reloads to index.html#

```
$("a.restaurantItem").click(function (event) {
  alert('Hello');
}
```

Any help and or advice would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$("a.restaurantItem")` is called once. It doesn't look for new elements. You need to use the event delegation syntax of `.on()` to match those dynamically created elements:

```
$('ul.special-list').on('click', 'a.restaurantItem', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // To stop the link from redirecting the browser
});
```

Comment: you can chain this after the `.append()` item and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need delegated event handlers for dynanic elements, and to prevent the default action on anchors (to avoid scrolling to top or following the href)

```
$('ul.special-list').on('click', 'a.restaurantItem', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Hello');
});
```

Comment: This has worked, many thanks your quick response, i had forgotten to add the even.preventDefault on my question code

Answer (score 0):

use `.on()` this way

```
$(document).on('click',"a.restaurantItem",function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Hello');
});
```